# Mass to energy in nuclear reaction

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics

According to my understanding we get a lot of energy during nuclear reaction because mass transforms to energy. According to picture below total mass remains the same after reaction.

[image]

Is the picture wrong?

Comment: Why do you think the mass stays the same? Look up the masses for individual neurons, a U-235 atom, a Ba-139 atom, and a Kr-95 atom and see if there is a discrepancy.  You can't tell from this diagram that the input and output masses are the same.

Comment: Although the masses of U-235 is very nearly 235u, Ba-139 is very nearly 139u, etc, they actually all differ from the value they ought to have, and those differences are what we are talking about.

Comment: on good atomic mass tables, we can find values with more than 8 significant figures...
You have to use them all!

Comment: Just because nobody has explicitly said this yet... the mass of a nucleus is _not_ the mass of the proton times the number of protons plus the mass of the neutron times the number of neutrons. In particular, the mass is _lower_ than what you would get from calculating an approximate mass this way. This is because of binding energy lowering the mass of atom. When a nuclear decay happens, the resulting atoms have more total binding energy, and thus lower total mass, and thus energy is realeased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The upper number to the left of each element (for example, the $235$ in $^{235}_{92}U$) is the number of protons and neutrons in its nucleus. This is, however, only a rough guide to the mass of an atom of that element. The mass of an atom of U-235 is $235.04$ [daltons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalton_(unit)), the mass of an atom of Kr-95 is $94.94$ daltons, and the mass of an atom of Ba-139 is $138.91$ daltons. The mass difference between the U-235 atom and its two fission products is

$235.04 - 94.94 - 138.91 = 1.19$ daltons

which is about $1100$ MeV. Some of this energy will be carried away by the energetic neutrons and gamma rays (which are not shown in the diagram), the remainder will be kinetic energy of the fission products i.e. heat.

Comment: You need also to account for the free neutrons. Doing this you get
$$1.01 + 235.04 - 94.94 - 138.91 - 2\cdot 1.01 = 0.18 \text{ daltons}$$
which is about $170$ MeV.

Comment: The Atomic Mass Evaluation (latest is 2020) is available at https://www-nds.iaea.org/amdc/ if you want more significant figures.

Comment: Yes , good table ! And the data is given in "u". Weird for a French person to see "daltons"!